# NodeJS require('./path/to/image/image.jpg') as base64

Tags: node.js, require

Is there a way to tell `require` that if file name ends with `.jpg` then it should return base64 encoded version of it?

```
var image = require('./logo.jpg');
console.log(image); // data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgA...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I worry about the *"why"*, but here is *"how"*:

```
var Module = require('module');
var fs     = require('fs');

Module._extensions['.jpg'] = function(module, fn) {
  var base64 = fs.readFileSync(fn).toString('base64');
  module._compile('module.exports="data:image/jpg;base64,' + base64 + '"', fn);
};

var image = require('./logo.jpg');
```

There's some serious issues with this mechanism: for one, the data for each image that you load this way will be kept in memory until your app stops (so it's not useful for loading lots of images), and because of that caching mechanism (which also applies to regular use of `require()`), you can only load an image into the cache once (requiring an image a second time, after its file has changed, will still yield the first—cached—version, unless you manually start cleaning the module cache).

In other words: you don't really want this.

Comment: I have a library which is designed to be used on Front-End. Inside of it is a lot of require('./path/to/image.jpg'). They transformed by browserify-transform-tools. So at the end I have one .js file which will be used by browser. Currently I need to use this lib from nodejs. Until your answer I had only one choice - compile, then use by node. Now I need not to recompile everything on each change.

Comment: A good reason to use this method is testing, in which in the final version are not determined or uploaded to CDN.

Comment: Anothe reason, is favicon. Or aws lambda.

Comment: @StanislauBuzunk that means Node should interpret the file contents as Base-64-encoded, which isn't the case here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `fs.createReadStream("/path/to/file")`

Comment: Why do you _need_ `require`? The `fs` module is the correct way of accessing the file system.

Comment: @vbarbarosh another reason as to why require('./logo.jpg') should not be used is that when you require it NodeJs will start interpreting it which means that file should have valid js code.