# Dynamic image path in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React project (made using `create-react-app`), I have an array of objects with the following format:

```
items : [{
    id:"test",
    title:"Test title",
    project_url:"/project/test",
    doc:"2018",
    description:"test description",
    link:"example.com",
    background_img:"../../../s.png",
    color:"#333333"
}]
```

I map these objects into elements to be displayed on the page:

```
_generateItems() {
    return this.state.items.map((item) => {
        return (
            <div className="item">
            <h3>{item.title}</h3>
            <div className="device" style={{backgroundImage:`url(${item.background_img})`}}/>
            <Link to={item.project_url}><div className="info_btn"><h6>More info</h6></div></Link>
            </div>
        )
    })
}
```

My problem is that I cannot get background image of the inner `div` to work. After scouring the internet, I tried to use template literals like so:

```
`url(${item.background_img})`
```

This allowed the project to compile and run without errors, and inspecting the `div` in the browser, I can see that it has the correct style. The image however does not appear on the `div`.

I am guessing it has to do with the way webpack handles static resources like images when it builds the project. How can I make it work?

Comment: it may be that the url `../../../filename` (which is relative) is not relative to the page you are on nor the css url. Can you switch the urls to absolute urls? `/path/to/file` (be aware of the leading `/`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your images served statically? If so, you should have a `Public` folder in your project's root directory (seeing that you have used `create-react-app` to set up your project).

Place your images (ie `s.png`) in the `Public` directory of your project, and then revise your code as follows:

```
items : [{
    id:"test",
    title:"Test title",
    project_url:"/project/test",
    doc:"2018",
    description:"test description",
    link:"example.com",
    background_img:"/s.png", // Update the image path  
    color:"#333333"
}]
```

Comment: This worked right away. However I'd also like to know if its possible to have webpack handle them, like one would with a predetermined path (`var img = require("/path/to/image")`)

Comment: Great to hear that it worked - that is possible however I'm not sure why you would want to do that? In any case this might help you with that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241734/nodejs-require-path-to-image-image-jpg-as-base64

If you've found the answer above helpful please consider accepting :-)

Comment: Of course, I was just waiting for the timeout. I'll take a look at the linked thread. Thanks for the help.